# Trouble replacing handlebars variable with input from API

Tags: javascript, api, handlebars.js

I'm attempting to create a simple weather API that replaces handlebars placeholder variables with user input of a city name linked to an api. It works very strangely, it will display the correct data after the next input is submitted. I.E. I submit "Dayton" and the placeholder data shows up again, then I submit "New York" and Dayton's correct info pops up. If I were to submit a third city, New York would display. Any ideas on why? Here's my code:

```
var currentWeather = {
    cityName: "London",
    temperature: 86,
    description: 'cloudy'
};

var addCurrentWeather = function(data) {


    var weather = {
        cityName: data.name,
        temperature: data.main.temp,
        description: data.weather[0].main
    }


};
var renderCurrentWeather = function () {
    var weather= currentWeather;
    var source = $('#weather-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source)
    var weatherHTML = template(currentWeather);

    $('#city').append(weatherHTML);

};


// fetch applying user input to grab data from api


    var fetchCurrentWeather = function (query) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + query + "&APPID=MYKEY",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                addCurrentWeather(data);
                renderCurrentWeather();


                currentWeather = {
                    cityName: data.name,
                    temperature: data.main.temp,
                    description: data.weather[0].main
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
    };




$('#search').on('click', function () {
    var search = $('#search-query').val();
    console.log(search);

fetchCurrentWeather(search);

});
renderCurrentWeather();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you expect from your code to do following in the `success` handler.

1. Update your global weather object
2. Use that global object to render your template

That does not happen because your function `addCurrentWeather` does essentially nothing as it updates a local variable and discards it.

So make sure that this function instead updates the global variable.

```
var addCurrentWeather = function(data) {
    currentWeather = {
        cityName: data.name,
        temperature: data.main.temp,
        description: data.weather[0].main
    }
};
```

and in the `success` handler you should have then only

```
addCurrentWeather(data);
renderCurrentWeather();
```

Reason why it then currently works the way it does is because after you call the render function you later update the global variable directly hence why this data is then used on next api fetch.

---

As a suggestion, try to avoid using global variables as it is easy to create bugs like this. Instead try to use pure functions as it will also help if you start unit test your code.

In your case have `addCurrentWeather` function accept data and `return` a weather object. And similarly have the render method accept weather object instead of reading it from global var.

Something like this

```
function getCurrentWeather(data) {
  return  {
    cityName: data.name,
    temperature: data.main.temp,
    description: data.weather[0].main
  }
};

function renderCurrentWeather(weather) {
  var source = $('#weather-template').html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source)
  var weatherHTML = template(currentWeather);
  $('#city').append(weatherHTML);
};

function fetchCurrentWeather(query) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + query + "&APPID=MYKEY",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      const weather = getCurrentWeather(data);
      renderCurrentWeather(weather);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus);
    }
  });
};

$('#search').on('click', function () {
  var search = $('#search-query').val();
  console.log(search);
  fetchCurrentWeather(search);
});

fetchCurrentWeather('London');
```